# My function does not work the first time its called when using onclick but works fine when using onload and I cannot seem to understand why

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a function that makes a button black when its clicked

```
const IDs = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

function loop() {
    if (gameOver === false) {
    for (let i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(`${IDs[i]}`).onclick = function loop2() {
            input = IDs[i].toLowerCase()
            document.getElementById(`${IDs[i]}`).style.backgroundColor = "black"
            }
    }
    }
};
```

The input part is for another reason but also does not work the first time, and the gameOver is a boolean that when you lose changes to true
Now the thing is that when I do this in the html it works:

```
<body onload="newWord();start();loop()">
    
    </style>
    <div class="div" onclick="compare()">
    <button id="A">A</button>
    <button id="B">B</button>
    <button id="C">C</button>
    <button id="D">D</button>
    <button id="E">E</button>
    <button id="F">F</button>
    <button id="G">G</button>
    <button id="H">H</button>
    <br>
    <button id="I">I</button>
    <button id="J">J</button>
    <button id="K">K</button>
    <button id="L">L</button>
    <button id="M">M</button>
    <button id="N">N</button>
    <button id="O">O</button>
    <button id="P">P</button>
    <button id="Q">Q</button>
    <br>
    <button id="R">R</button>
    <button id="S">S</button>
    <button id="T">T</button>
    <button id="U">U</button>
    <button id="V">V</button>
    <button id="W">W</button>
    <button id="X">X</button>
    <button id="Y">Y</button>
    <button id="Z">Z</button>
</div>
</body>
<script src="hangman.js"></script>
```

the compare() function compares the input but in my testing it was not the problem and the other 2 functions where there before I made the problematic function so I suppose they are not the problem either.
but at first I did this

```
<body onload="newWord();start()">
    
    </style>
    <div class="div" onclick="loop();compare()">
```

the rest stayed the same and I cannot understand why the first one works but this one doesn't
If the rest of the code needs to be provided please tell it and I will do it
-Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes I am quite new

I tried to make a function that turns a button black once clicked but it didn't work and just out of curiosity I tried another way that didn't think would work but it worked and I do not understand why and for that reason I want someone to explain the difference

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: '${IDs[i]}' - you are mixing jquery and straight javascript.  And i is a variable -> '${IDs['+i+']}'

Comment: @dev4life sorry I am kinda new and don't know what that means can you explain in a little more detail? I have been using ${} from when I started and it didn't cause any problems so I don't really understand why it would cause a problem now

Comment: @0stone0 I will try to add one tomorrow since I currently don't have access to the computer in which the program is written, so sorry for that inconvenience

Comment: I changed the code a bit and now it works and I understand why, I basically included the compare() function in the loop() function and it fixed everything